# uploading file in postgres database using java servlet

Tags: java, html, postgresql, servlets

Hi I want to upload file in postgres database using java servlet but I am not understanding how to set prepared statement for file as we should use bytea for postgres not blob. Can you help to resolve this issue.
I tried using getBytes(), BinaryStream but I am getting errors as

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/postgresql/jdbc3g/Jdbc3gPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V is abstract
```

Below is my html code

```
<form method="post" action="Upload"  enctype='multipart/form-data'>

        <select id="onelevel" name="onelevel"></select>
        <br><br>
        <select id="twolevel" name="twolevel"></select>
        <br><br>
         <select id="threelevel" name="threelevel"></select>
         <br><br>
         <select id="fourlevel" name="fourlevel"></select>
         <br><br>
          <select id="fivelevel" name="fivelevel"></select>
          <br><br>


<div class="docu" name="docu">

  <input type="file" name="data"  accept=".doc,.docx,.xml,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" >
  <button>Upload</button>

    </div>



</form>
```

Here is my java code

```
package fileupload;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import dbConnection.Dbconn;

@MultipartConfig
public class Upload extends HttpServlet {



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // gets values of text fields
        String onelevel = request.getParameter("onelevel");
        String twolevel = request.getParameter("twolevel");
        String threelevel = request.getParameter("threelevel");
        String fourlevel = request.getParameter("fourlevel");
        String fivelevel = request.getParameter("fivelevel");


        System.out.println(onelevel);







        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Part filePart = request.getPart("data");
        if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }

        Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
        String message = null;
        Statement st = null;// message will be sent back to client

        try {
            // connects to the database
              conn = Dbconn.getConnection();
              st = conn.createStatement();

            // constructs SQL statement
            String sql = "INSERT INTO files1 (board,syllabus, class,subject,chapters) values (?, ?, ?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, onelevel);
            statement.setString(2, twolevel);
            statement.setString(3, threelevel);
            statement.setString(4, fourlevel);
            statement.setString(5, fivelevel);

           /* if (inputStream != null) {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                statement.setBlob(6, inputStream);
            }
 */
            // sends the statement to the database server
            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // sets the message in request scope
            request.setAttribute("Message", message);

            // forwards to the message page
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.html").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE files
(
  board text,
  syllabus text,
  class text,
  subject text,
  data bytea,
  chapters text
)
```

Comment: If you're getting `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`, you've got driver problems. What version driver are you compiling against and what version driver are you running with?

Comment: jdk-1.8 version  ,  postgres-9.4 version

Comment: What version **driver** are you compiling against and what version **driver** are you running with?

Comment: when I am running application I got as   Driver Name: PostgreSQL Native Driver
Driver Version: PostgreSQL 8.2 JDBC3g with SSL (build 504)

Comment: Use setBytes instead of setBlob. You will have to convert your input stream to a byte array before calling setBytes.

Comment: @dsp_user That's not good advice. It's a lot better to stream it.

Comment: Your driver is old as Harrison Ford. Get a newer suitable one from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql

Comment: @Kayaman, he already has the file on the server. The only thing he has to do is store it in the DB. If, however, the file is large, I'd probably recommend storing it on the file system and saving only a link (path) to it in the DB (retrieving the file from the server would be then trivial ).

Comment: @dsp_user No. He's streaming the file from the client. Your suggestion is bad in two ways. He doesn't need to store the file on the server, and he certainly doesn't need to store the file in **memory** to be able to put it in the database. He's got the right idea, but an ancient driver. You on the other hand are completely off and shouldn't be giving bad advice. Also, you should be using `setBinaryStream()`. No need to go through `Blob`.

Comment: Well, I simply offered a suggestion that I thought was right. The OP can choose what's best for him.

Comment: ya ok I added new driver now version is Driver Version: 42.1.4

Comment: Now I am getting this error org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 6, number of columns: 5.But my table has all 6 columns  . Below is my table                                                                                   CREATE TABLE files1
(
  board text,
  syllabus text,
  class text,
  subject text,
  chapters text,
  data bytea
)

Comment: Your query only defines 5 columns and 5 `?` placeholders.

Comment: @dsp_user I hope you learned your suggestion was wrong. When you can stream, do it. You don't want to waste memory unnecessarily, and if you're working with large files, you **can't** do it. This is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: Ya guys finally my data has been stored in the form of "PK\003\004\024\000\006\000\010\000\000\000!\000\345b\365\363\317\001\000\000\201\010\000\000\023\000\010\002[Content_Types].xml \242\004\002(\240\000\002\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\00 (...)"

Comment: Uh, okay. Congratulations I guess.

Comment: But when I want to retrieve it how can I change Binary format to readable format

Comment: Thank you Kayman, dsp_user for your suggestions